# How many graphs can someone store in JanusGraph?

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph

I am trying to build a system that uses `JanusGraph` as its Graph Database engine and `Cassandra` as the storage backend, but I am still in the designing phase so I have a question that need an answer to avoid trade-offs in the future or re-building.

I want to know how many graphs can I store in a single `JanusGraph` server, so for example can I store over 10000 Graphs or no ?

Does `JanusGraph` load all graphs to the memory or only load to memory the called graph and then dispose it to free memory ?

If that is the case I guess I can save as many graphs as I can but I can't find an answer to confirm this before starting to build and code.

According to `JanusGraph` in this [link](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/basics/technical-limitations/#size-limitation), the size limit is set to `JanusGraph` but does that means for each graph or the server in general ? as if it is for server in general then we can grasp the amount of graphs that can be supported but if this is the size limit for each graph then we can't decide the amount of graphs that the server can hold.

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

With Cassandra as the backend, each graph is mapped to a keyspace. The graphs are not really stored in the Gremlin Server, they are stored in Cassandra. The Gremlin Server, using the JanusGraph libraries, just connects to a Cassandra node.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, so you mean that JanusGraph can host 10000 graphs or more, sort of speaking ? what about the indexes of those graphs, I mean they take space from the JanusGraph or they are loaded when needed ?